# Is there a method to quote curly braces in a Java String?

Tags: java, string, escaping, curly-braces

I must execute this Java String `" find ./tmp -name .SYNC -exec rm -rf {} \;"` 
with `getRuntime().exec(command)`. But it doesn't work!

I think maybe the problem are the curly braces, because they are highlighted in yellow.

I've already tried with `\{} , \{\}\ , '{}' , "'{}'"`, without success.

You can check my code below.

```
String[] command={"find","./tmp","-name",".SYNC","-exec","rm","-rf","{}","\;" };

String res = Shell.executeCommand(command);

public static String executeCommand(String[] command){
   ...
   p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
   ..
}
```

Comment: What's the current output or error message?

Comment: what is your desired output? and please format your question properly.

Comment: Just looking at it, the problem's probably within the fact that you're using `\;` instead of `\\;`, but that's just a guess.

Comment: Are you running the code on Windows or  a Linux Distro ?

Comment: does it work on the shell? I think the braces must be escaped like the semi-colon (must use two backslashes to option one in java)

Comment: No output, 'cause it doesn't execute it...

Comment: I would like to remove all of these '.SYNC' hidden files in a certain directory... I've tried also with \\; without success.. I'm running it in Linux, and yes, it works on the Shell... I've already had some problems with previous commands, because Java 'manipulate' strings in some way before sending them to the system, I think...

Answer (score 1):

Try with this: using `\\;` instead of `\;`

[image]